# Regular Expression for number ###\######-##

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a number with pattern `000\000000-00` and I would like to generate a regex(Regular expression) for it.

I've tried this but it failed:

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]){3}[\\][0-9]{6}[\-][0-9]{2}$/", $number)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to include a literal `\` slash in your regular expression, you need to "quad" escape like this: `\\\\`:

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]{3})\\\\[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}$/", $number)
```

because `\` have special meaning for both regular expressions and strings.

Also you don't need the character classes so I just removed them.

Comment: Also note that you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, just makes it a bit easier to read... for some people, at least XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes that's correct. Thank you. I prefer to use `[0-9]` because it's faster than `\d` when you don't need the luxury of matching Unicode numbers.